# address of non static member function template

Tags: c++, templates, static, pointer-to-member

I'm trying to understand if it's possible to take the address of a non-static member function template. Below does not work and using `&sz<int>` results in other errors. What is the right way to get the address of non static member function template?

```
311 struct XYZ
312 {
313    template <typename Z>
314    void sz()
315    {
316    }
317 
318    void func()
319    {
320       auto z = sz<int>;
321    }
322 };
```

results in an error

```
vs.cc:320:16: error: reference to non-static member function must be called; did you mean to call it with no arguments?
      auto z = sz<int>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter that `void sz()` is a template because `sz<int>` is a member function. There is no notion of "address" in C++ - this is an implementation detail. What you can have is a *pointer to member function*, and the syntax for it is:

```
auto z = &XYZ::sz<int>;
```

To call it inside `func()`, you need the following syntax:

```
(this->*z)();
```